# Accidentally Uninstalled Network manager

Tags: command-line

Before my network wasn't working, and I was told to uninstall the network manager, but now, I don't know how to get it back...

Does anyone have the steps to not only fix my network manager, but also fix my network through terminal commands?

Thank you!

Comment: I'mnot sure how to reinstall, but if you can't get online to download the required packages, you might be able to use [THIS GUIDE](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html) to help, since you can't remove the network manager from a live cd/drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command on terminal to install network manager,

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```